# Can I put nail clipper, tweezer and razors in Emirates hold luggage?

Tags: luggage, emirates, prohibited-items

Travelling with Emirates airline, can I keep a nail clipper which has a small knife built into it, tweezer or razors in my hold baggage, not in a carry-on bag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course you may. Weapons and such like are of concern when in hand luggage (so might be used in the cabin). Luggage in the hold is not accessible during the flight so as long as not explosive, inflammable, radioactive etc almost anything goes.

What [Emirates](http://www.emirates.com/uk/english/plan_book/essential_information/baggages/checked-baggage.aspx) state is not allowable in checked luggage is:

> Personal motorised vehicles are not allowed on board
>
> For safety reasons, we can’t accept personal motorised vehicles such
>   as hoverboards, mini-Segways and smart or self-balancing wheels on our
>   flights. We can’t carry them either as checked-in baggage or as hand
>   luggage as they contain large lithium batteries. This regulation still
>   applies even if you’re connecting to our flights from an airline that
>   has accepted them.
>
> Items containing explosives are not allowed on board
>
> All fireworks and any other items containing explosives, for example
>   Christmas crackers, firecrackers, bottle rockets, poppers and
>   sparklers are forbidden to be carried either as carry-on baggage or as
>   checked baggage on our flights.

There are some other items, depending on for example any interlining carrier, but these do not disallow soap, shampoo are similar liquids.

Comment: This means even cleansing bars, shampoos and other liquids? I guess liquids will be subject to restrictions depending on each country.

Comment: @user3938033 As a rule of thumb, in checked luggage everything is allowed that is (1) not dangerous to transport and (2) not prohibited or restricted to export/possess/import in the destination of departure countries. All non-dangerous liquids are fine, and so are razors, scissors, etc. Sometimes "dangerous to transport" is not so obvious, though, as, e.g., in the case of lithium batteries. "Food liquids" may be restricted by the import regulations of the arrival country.